# Using History API in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, history-tracking

We have a Single Page Application, where we have multiple components display on the screen. The components displays on the screen depending on what button they clicked. Now, i'd like to be able to use the "browser's" back button to sort of go back to the original state.

MainComponent.cmp

```
<aura:component> 
<ligtning:button label="Show Screen 1" />
<ligtning:button label="Show Screen 2" />
<ligtning:button label="Show Screen 3" />

<aura:if ifTrue="{!v.show1}">
  <c:screencomponent1 />
</aura:if>
<aura:if ifTrue="{!v.show2}">
  <c:screencomponent2 />
</aura:if>
<aura:if ifTrue="{!v.show3}">
  <c:screencomponent3 />
</aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

NOTE: The code above is just a snippet for illustration so pardon if there's syntax errors.

This is all in one page application, and essentially, when a user clicks "Show Screen 2" the screen will display the screen 2 component(we are just showing or hiding the component via aura:if).

Now, let's say I am now showing screen 2 component, I'd like to be able to use the History API such that when the user clicks the "browser's back" button it will go back to the very first state (screen 2 component is hidden).

Has anyone been able to manage history api for single page application in lightning aura?

Essentially, my dilemma is sort of the described in this article but I've not been able to make it work in lightning aura: https://frontendjournal.com/html5-pushstate-and-single-page-apps/

Comment: To be clear, is this in a Lightning Community, or a standalone Lightning App?

Comment: We can add a parameter in the URL, and maybe use [Is Url Addressable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:isUrlAddressable/documentation)

Comment: @sfdcfox this would be in Lightning Community and Salesforce LEX app and Salesforce Mobile. We’re using the same component for both contaibers.